# Why is my query plan generating an index scan?

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a relatively straight forward query:

```
    SELECT o.id
    FROM dbo.table1 o
    LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 n (NOLOCK)
        ON o.first = n.second and n.first = @Var1
    WHERE 
        (o.fourth in (@Var4, @Var5) or o.fifth = @Var6) AND
        (o.first = @Var1 or n.first = @Var1) AND
        (
            o.second = @Var2 OR
            o.second like (@Var2 + '[^a-zA-Z]%') OR
            o.third like (@Var3 + '[^a-zA-Z]%')
        )
```

But whenever I check out the query plan, I am doing an index scan.

The non-clustered index I have is (on table1):

```
First ASC,
Fourth ASC,
Fifth ASC,
Second ASC,
Third ASC

Include: id
```

Why a scan? Doesn't my index cover it? I also have the correct indexes for table2, so I am not worried there.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only places where you are using the `First` column from table 1 are in places where a failure to have a match is not necessarily a failure for the whole query

- inside the `ON` of a `LEFT JOIN`
- On only one side of an `OR` operator

Therefore, it cannot start to *benefit* from using an index with `First` as the first column, since literally *any* value in that column might be a valid part of the final result.

Comment: Makes sense. In that case, I don't really have a concrete starting point. Would rewriting the query be a better option?

Comment: @user2124871 - difficult to tell when everything is so abstract. If the query is *logically correct*, then any re-write that's also logically correct will probably have exactly the same query plan.

Comment: So I tried to get around the issue, but, just like you stated, I got the same query plan. Next solution is to break this into separate queries and join the results. Thanks for your input - appreciate it.